# laravel socialite other accounts information

Tags: facebook, laravel, facebook-graph-api, laravel-socialite, laravel-5.5

Hi I am using sociliate for social login of facebook and other social accounts. Its properly login in and all the permissions but i was just wondering why it doenst have a proper documentation ? 
Secondarily I want to get complete details of an account for facebook i.e

```
like this : https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/somename?access_token=EAAByZCif65pcBAPPndJuMfDuBlfsjKGFzQZA9gZBo0X8ZAJ665WRhDuyqiKjsDiQre24IfJAiHQvQOHT4xU6AqAXET6KLb5ZCqQWITESHY8Ht40FhpG2Y9nZCZCg1slVcez2cD789ZB8Xdd2Mt6COKWo4GieOy9bgrDUH4DngX9sHgZDZD
```

now how can i do this via **socialite** ? I cant seem to get my head around it..

I can do it via custom request calls of graph API but i want to do it via socialite.